# How to use multiple nodejs server on same nginx domain server? keep getting error

Tags: nginx, centos7, nginx-reverse-proxy

Below is my full nginx.conf on centos 7 /etc/nginx/nginx.conf instance, The main domain works mytestdomain.com  but the mytestdomain.com/stonks give "Cannot GET /stonks/" error. I tried to follow many stack and digital ocean solutions but it didnt work,

I tested the port 3000 with "curl localhost:3000" and it works.

Appreciate your help...............................................

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

 events {
    worker_connections 1024;
 }

 http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
   tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

 
    server {
        server_name  mytestdomain.com;
#        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
         location /stonks {
         proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
         proxy_http_version 1.1;
         proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
           proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
         location / {
         proxy_pass http://localhost:3210;
         proxy_http_version 1.1;
         proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
           proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/ak/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/akap/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}


    server {
    if ($host = akash-backend.sushilsampangrai.com.np) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen       80;
        listen       [::]:80;
        server_name  akash-backend.sushilsampangrai.com.np;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}}
```

Comment: I think your problem is quite related to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67061165/host-static-website-and-api-service-on-same-server-using-nginx/67062705#67062705. Maybe prefix your API by "/stonks" as described in my answer?

Comment: Oh got it, thanks alot...